# Output port continuous assignment problem

Tags: verilog

I have the code below, which is an array of shift registers connected to each other.

i.e., Sin->sr1->sr2->...sr14->sr15->sr16->Sout.

```
module Array #(
    parameter NCOL = 4,
    parameter NROW = 4
)
(   
    input clk,          
    input reset,        
    input Sin,
    output Sout    
);
    
    // NCOL * NROW shift registers 
    wire [NCOL - 1: 0] shift_reg [NROW - 1: 0]; 

    genvar i, j;

    /* Connected array of SRs */
    generate
    for (j = 0; j < NCOL; j=j+1) begin: sr_y
        for (i = 0; i < NROW; i=i+1) begin: sr_x
                sr sr_inst (
                .clk(clk),
                .reset(reset),
                .Sin(shift_reg[i][j]),
                .Sout(shift_reg[i+1][j])
            );
        end
    end
    // connect 4th SR in each column to the 1st SR in the next column
    for (j = 0; j < NCOL - 1; j=j+1) begin: shift_y
        assign shift_reg[0][j+1] = shift_reg[NROW-1][j];
    end

    endgenerate

    /* Connect the shift register endpoints to the input and output of the module */
    assign shift_reg[0][0] = Sin;
    assign Sout = shift_reg[NROW-1][NCOL-1];

endmodule


module sr #(parameter WIDTH = 16)(
    input clk,
    input reset,        
    input Sin,          
    output Sout         
);
    
    reg [WIDTH-1:0] sr_data;
    reg sout;           /* Latched shift register output */
    
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset) begin
            sr_data <= 16'd0;
        end else begin
                sr_data[0] <= Sin;
                sr_data[WIDTH-1:1]  <= sr_data[WIDTH-2:0];
        end
    end

    always @(negedge clk) begin
        if (reset == 1'b1) begin
            sout <= 1'b0;
        end else begin
            sout <= sr_data[WIDTH-1];
        end
    end
    
    assign Sout = sout;
    
endmodule
```

I got some errors (below) when trying to compile. I have declared the ports as wires, but I still have the same problem. Could you help solve the errors as I can't seem to see the issue?

```
warning: ignoring out of bounds l-value array access shift_reg[4].
error: Output port expression must support continuous assignment.
     : Port 6 (Sout) of sr is connected to shift_reg[(i)+('sd1)][j]
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared the signal as:

```
wire [NCOL - 1: 0] shift_reg [NROW - 1: 0];
```

When you plug in the parameter values, this resolves to:

```
wire [3:0] shift_reg [3:0];
```

This is an array of 4 elements (0 to 3),  each of which is 4 bits wide.

The problem is this line inside the `for` loops:

```
            .Sout(shift_reg[i+1][j])
```

When `i` is set to its maximum value of 3 in the loop, `i+1` is 4, which resolves to:

```
            .Sout(shift_reg[4][j])
```

But, there is no `shift_reg[4]` element of the array.  That explains the warning message.  You are selecting an element which is not in the array ("out of bounds").

I don't understand the error message, but I suspect it will go away if you fix the code that produces the warning.

Comment: yes, thanks, I tried [i] instead of [i+1] and it went without errors/warnings. The warning should have been the error :)